# Why can't commas be in Javascript object keys?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, firebase

This is an odd thing to ask I am aware, but I am very much a newbie and can't seem to wrap my head around this. I have a Javascript object sent to me via firebase that looks like this:

```
var blob = {
    matt@email,com: {         //notice the comma because periods are illegal in keys
       email: "matt@email.com" //actual email with period
       name: "Matt Sanford"
       pic: "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-LeQrq-_KjJE/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAoI/4l6r2HNdock/photo.jpg"
       provider: "google"
       uid: "0000000000000000"
      }
   }  
}
```

I am trying to access the inner most tree via the console like so: `console.log(blob.matt@email,com) //throws an error because of an invalid token`
even though it should return the object with `email`, `name`, etc.

However when I tried the same structure like so:

```
var blob = {foo: {bar: true} }
console.log(blob.foo) //output '{bar: true}'
```

There are two things I am wondering, is having the initial key with the modified email illegal because of the commas or is there not a way to read such a key in javascript? Recommendations are appreciated because I am just learning as I go along here.

**Update**

How would I go about accessing the keys dynamically? Clearly it would be impossible to input each key dynamically. How would I read it without knowing what exactly the key name is?

Comment: Two things, **1.** When the key of an object contain special symbol, **use quotes** **2** Use comma as separator between two elements of object

Comment: `console.log( blob['matt@email,com'] )`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you posted is not a json object, it's a javascript object. JSON would have all its keys quoted.

Comma's are definitely allowed, but you cannot use the standard `obj.property` syntax like this:

```
console.log(blob.matt@email,com)
```

You must do:

```
console.log(blob['matt@email,com']);
```

Comment: so what Firebase is sending back to me is a javascript object? not json?

Comment: If firebase is sending you something back that has `var` in it, and it's in the exact structure you posted, then yes... it's not sending you back json. However, I don't think you copy pasted something that firebase sent you back, as there's a syntax error in the sample as well. This tells me you probably re-typed it incorrectly by-hand.

Comment: In JSON there's no `var`, there's no comments and every property and string value must be surrounded by double quotes.

Comment: What they send me is put in dataSnapshot in my callback function and I assign var blob = dataSnapshot.val() from there. I typed and omitted some things for privacy

Comment: @MattSanford: Firebase's DataSnapshot.val() will return a JavaScript object for the JSON that is in the snapshot. If you want it to become JSON again, `JSON.stringify(blob)`.